# Merge 2 mysql tables with the same rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 mysql tables with the same rows, on both the tables some information is missing and now I need to merge the two tables into one table with the complete information.

This is how the tables look like:

Table1:

```
Name | Adres       | Postal
------------------------------
Koen | Stationsweg | 
     | Marktplein  | 4342FG
```

Table 2:

```
Name | Adres       | Postal
------------------------------
     | Stationsweg | 4368RT
Bert | Marktplein  |
```

The final table needs to look like:

```
Name | Adres       | Postal
------------------------------
Koen | Stationsweg | 4368RT
Bert | Marktplein  | 4342FG
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  MAX(COALESCE(a.Name, b.name)) name,
        a.adres,
        MAX(COALESCE(a.postal, b.postal)) postal
FROM    table1 a
        LEFT JOIN table2 b
            ON a.adres = b.adres
GROUP   BY a.adres
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/28c60c/2)

if you want the result of the above query to be inserted let's say on another table: `table3`, Use `INSERT INTO...SELECT`

```
INSERT  INTO table3 (name, adres, postal)
SELECT  MAX(COALESCE(a.Name, b.name)) name,
        a.adres,
        MAX(COALESCE(a.postal, b.postal)) postal
FROM    table1 a
        LEFT JOIN table2 b
            ON a.adres = b.adres
GROUP   BY a.adres
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/10cd4/1)

Comment: i tried to translate your comment -- *Thanks for the reply! it is now fixed.* Is it correct? If so, You're welcome `:D`